# how do I make it easy for my parents to run this Powershell command?

Tags: powershell, automation, windows-10

I am not a programmer and my parents' Windows 10 PC tends to loose its start menu and cortana processes, resulting in start menu not showing up at all when the start icon is clicked.

I made a quick search and found + tested this **Powershell** command and it worked:

```
Get-AppxPackage | % { Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppxManifest.xml" -verbose }
```

I wish to turn this command into a shortcut/batchfile that executes the command and restarts the PC whenever the desktop icon is double clicked, in order to avoid explaining to my parents what to do to fix the problem. Can any one help me out please? 
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

you can encode the command and put the whole thing into a single batch file (no .ps1 necessary)

details here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timid/2014/03/26/powershell-encodedcommand-and-round-trips/

or you can use this function

https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/Encode-Text.ps1

first, either use Get-Content or Get-Clipboard (copy your whole script to the clipboard) to encode your desired script

```
PS> Encode-Text (Get-Clipboard | out-string)
RwBlAHQALQBBAHAAcAB4AFAAYQBjAGsAYQBnAGUAIAB8ACAAJQAgAHsAIABBAGQAZAAtAEEAcABwAHgAUABhAGMAawBhAGcAZQAgAC0ARABpAHMAYQBiAGwAZQBEAGUAdgBlAGwAbwBwAG0AZQBuAHQATQBvAGQAZQAgAC0AUgBlAGcAaQBzAHQAZQByACAAIgAkACgAJABfAC4ASQBuAHMAdABhAGwAbABMAG8AYwBhAHQAaQBvAG4AKQBcAEEAcABwAHgATQBhAG4AaQBmAGUAcwB0AC4AeABtAGwAIgAgAC0AdgBlAHIAYgBvAHMAZQAgAH0ADQAKAA==
```

then you can use that in your batch file like so

```
powershell -encodedcommand RwBlAHQALQBBAHAAcAB4AFAAYQBjAGsAYQBnAGUAIAB8ACAAJQAgAHsAIABBAGQAZAAtAEEAcABwAHgAUABhAGMAawBhAGcAZQAgAC0ARABpAHMAYQBiAGwAZQBEAGUAdgBlAGwAbwBwAG0AZQBuAHQATQBvAGQAZQAgAC0AUgBlAGcAaQBzAHQAZQByACAAIgAkACgAJABfAC4ASQBuAHMAdABhAGwAbABMAG8AYwBhAHQAaQBvAG4AKQBcAEEAcABwAHgATQBhAG4AaQBmAGUAcwB0AC4AeABtAGwAIgAgAC0AdgBlAHIAYgBvAHMAZQAgAH0ADQAKAA==
```

Answer (score 2):

You could execute the PowerShell script via a batch file.

Batch file:

```
set powerscriptPath=C:\Example.ps1

PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%powerscriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

This will bypass the execution policies on the computer allowing the script to run in Administrator mode too. **NOTE**: You will need to edit the `powerscriptPath` to point to your PowerShell script location, I just used `C:\Example.ps1` as an example.

You will want to add `Restart-Computer -Force` to the end of your PowerShell script to restart the computer

```
Get-AppxPackage | % { Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppxManifest.xml" -verbose }
Restart-Computer -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a bat file which executes powershell with that file. Then add a shortcut to the bat file

Comment: Didn't know this was possible ;)
Good idea

Comment: @Matt because by default, ps1 files open in notepad instead of executing in powershell

Answer (score 1):

I am really unsure why you would run a batch file just to call a powershell script! Talk about hokey approaches to a non-problem.

To call a powershell script is really no different than calling a batch script:

It's simply path to PowerShell, and the script path as a parameter:

`"%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"  "C:\users\austinfrench\desktop\example.ps1"`

You can also use the exact same format as the target for a desktop shortcut.